# Django: ManyToMany relationship and database duplicity

Tags: django, database-design, relational-database, django-orm

So I have models `GeneralUser`, `Business`, `Brand`, `Bottle`.

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(GeneralUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, related_name="businesses")

class Brand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, unique=True)
    businesses = models.ManyToManyField(Business, related_name="brands", blank=False)

class Bottle(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=550, default="", null=False, blank=False)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, related_name="bottles")
```

Each `Brand` can belong to many businesses, and each `Business` can hold many brands.

My goal is to not have `Brand` objects created if they already exist in the database.

I've built a `Bottle ModelForm` which also allows the user to choose and create a new `Brand` in the process.

But the problem I'm facing now is this:

- Users only see brands associated with the Business.
- User 1 created Brand `X` → OK
- User 2 tries to create Brand `X` → IntegrityError unique constraint failed.

Which I totally understand and not surprised by. My question is what's the best solution in this case?

The `BottleCreateForm` is pretty standard:

```
class BottleCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bottle
        fields = ['name', 'brand' ,  'vintage', 'capacity']
```

But I'm also adding an "Add New" HTML button, which calls the brand create view:

```
def add_brand(request):

    response_data = {}

    if request.method == "POST":
        response_data['success'] = False

        form = BrandCreateForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            print("form valid!")
            users_business = Business.objects.filter(owner=request.user).first()
            form.save(commit=True)
            users_business.brands.add(form.instance)

            response_data['pk'] = form.instance.id
            response_data['success'] = True

            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(response_data),
                content_type="application/json"
            )

        else:
            response_data['errors'] = form.errors

            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(response_data),
                content_type="application/json"
            )
```

Comment: You should show the form and view.

Comment: @danielroseman it can get a little unwieldy here because the view is `index` but inside it there's a a `BottleCreateForm` that can also invoke a modal which calls `brand_create()` for creating brands, which is an AJAXified form itself. Which one would you like me to show?

Comment: @danielroseman I've added the BottleForm and the brand_create_view

Comment: If your form is valid, check that brand with the same data already exist. If so, do not call `form.save` and get id from DB instead, then pass it to `brands.add`

Comment: @SergeyZherevchuk but the form isn’t valid by definition because the database throws IntegrityError..(?)

Comment: Your form is for `Bottle` model, it doesn't check any uniqueness. In any case `is_valid` method can't throw any db error, it returns boolean value. Try to debug it (print something before `form.is_valid` method call and after (in success branch)